# Menu with numbers like the one for special characters (accents)?

Tags: applescript, contextual-menu

I would like to create a script to help searching a term in a website, depending on the site chosen. For the menu, I thought of having a menu such as the one that appears after we hold a certain, character, say 'a':

[image: Numbered menu for special characters]

Depending on the number typed, a different websearch is opened in a new window.

Any insight on how to get this with AppleScript or similar?

Comment: I doubt what you want to do is possible.  Have a look inside system/library/input methods/pressandhold.app to see what governs the behavior of the popup accent menu.

Comment: What if I want to create such an interface myself, which tools should I use? Sorry about the basic question :)